# How to hide and display alert in asp.net using c#

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net, bootstrap-modal

So I have a simple asp.net application that when a button is clicked I want to give the user a success alert or error alert depending on their submission.
What I'm stuck in is while I'm able to keep my message hidden I can't make it appear when the asp:button is clicked.

This is the bootstrap alert I want hidden:

```
<div class="alert alert-success collapse" role="alert">
                        <a href="#" class ="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
                        This is a success alert—check it out!</div>
```

And this is the c# code I'm using to try to call it:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Alert", 
                    "<script>$(document).ready(function(){ $('.alert-success').show(); " +
                    "$('.alert-danger'); }); </script>");
```

Couldn't find much online for the c# code so settled on that.
What's wrong with what I have, and how can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add an attribute `ClientIDMode` to the button and extend code in `RegisterClientScriptBlock` so it attaches listener to the button.

[ClientIDMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode?view=netframework-4.8)

> The ClientID value is set to the value of the ID property. If the
>   control is a naming container, the control is used as the top of the
>   hierarchy of naming containers for any controls that it contains.

```html
<asp:Button ID="button" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="Button" />
```

```cs
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Alert", 
                    @"<script>$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#button').click(function() {
    $('.alert-success').show();
  })

});</script>");
```

**Example**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#button').click(function() {
    $('.alert-success').show();
  })
  
});
```

```css
.alert {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div>
  <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a> This is a success alert—check it out!</div>
<!--That would be asp:button-->
<button id="button">Show Alert</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey thank you so much, it works great but I'm new to asp.net and I was wondering where this .alert {
  display: none;
} 
goes to? Great answer though, its exactly what I wanted.

Comment: add a `style` tag and put it there. If you don't like it as a alternative add `style` attribute to the button like ` <asp:Button ID="button" style="display: none" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="Button" />`